# Rotated button Espresso Test Click Not Working

Tags: android, android-espresso

I was playing with espresso around and I noticed that one of my buttons is failing to click. I tried to move it around on the screen and everything to make it be automatically clicked, but failed. Then I noticed that it had a `rotation=180`. And by removing it The problem seemed to be resolved, but it is needed.

Here is my code for the test:

```
@Test
public void orderUp() throws Exception {
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.move_up)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    onView(withText("Up")).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(menuActivityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

So, **how to make the test case work for a rotated button?**

Edit: 'Error Log indicating that The Toast wasn't found I Think'

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingRootException: Matcher 'with decor view not is <DecorView@1ec572[MainActivity]>' did not match any of the following roots: [Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@449fd58, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@449fd58, has-window-focus=true, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x103046c needsMenuKey=2 naviIconColor=0}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x103046c needsMenuKey=2 naviIconColor=0}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}}]
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1567)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:90)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:52)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:291)
at com.tabbara.mohammad.trailedsheetexample.ExampleInstrumentedTest.orderUp(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:433)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1967)
```

Comment: What was the error log when the test clicks on a rotated button?

Comment: @Aaron added The error Log for the testcase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ViewActions.click](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions#click()) finds coordinates of a view on the screen, and then performs/simulates a tap on the coordinates. I'm not exactly sure but it seems that `setRotation` may have affected coordinates calculation. An alternative solution would be creating a custom click action:

```
public static ViewAction forceClick() {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return allOf(isClickable(), isEnabled());
        }

        @Override public String getDescription() {
            return "force click";
        }

        @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            view.performClick();
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
        }
    };
}
```

This action performs click on the view by invoking `performClick()` without finding its coordinates. But make sure the view has the click listener attached in the app

```
onView(withId(R.id.move_up)).perform(forceClick());
```